# Returning a STL container of unique pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm not knowledgeable about STL containers and their inner workings but is it valid to declare the following?

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<Object>, 4> p_object;
```

From what I know, `std::array<std::shared_ptr<Object>> p_object` works but I get a compiler error when I try to declare an array with unique pointers.  Is this because the std::array tries to copy the unique pointers?  If I want a collection of unique pointers what STL container should I use?  I read somewhere that its better to simply use raw pointers with STL containers.  Is this true?

**EDIT:**

I realized that the error is not originating from  declaring the array but rather from the method:

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<tp::QuadTree>, 4> get_children(){ return children; }
```

I'm guessing that by returning an array of unique pointers I'm creating a copy of the unique pointers. I had assumed RVO wouldn't create a copy. How exactly should I rewrite this function?

**EDIT2**

The error message reads

deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = tp::QuadTree, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr]' used here

'used here' referred to the array template class

Comment: what error have you got?

Comment: What's the problem? [It seems to work as you intend](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d0f32b3bd542f21).

Comment: Not sure if it's directly related to the fact that I declared an array with a unique pointer but I get an error reading:

"deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = tp::QuadTree, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<tp::QuadTree>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr<tp::QuadTree>]'| used here"

'used here' refers to the array template class

Comment: @kpark Please post the error message in the question, not the comments. That error indicates you're trying to copy construct a `unique_ptr` somewhere. You'll need to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for us to be able to help you.

Comment: AFAIK, STL containers should work fine with movable-only types like `unique_ptr`, as long as you don't do an operation on the container that requires an element-wise copy. You example code works for me, and on [ideone](https://ideone.com/1GVzJa). It is most likely that your version of the standard library doesn't yet support movable-only elements (or doesn't implement it correctly).

Comment: By the naming convention alone, I'm assuming this is a member of a containing object class. If so, that object class likely has a default copy-constructor or a custom one implemented by you. In either case, you cannot copy one object's `p_objeect` to the other's, something that will be implicit if you're using (intentionally or otherwise) the implicit copy-ctor of the containing class. You need a *custom* copy-ctor for said-class that specifically does *not* copy the `p_object` member.

Comment: And to answer your question about `get_children()`, return a reference (the `const`-ness is up to you).

Comment: Post your error message inside question!

Comment: RVO only applies to local variables, not data members (as this appears to be) or other non-local variables. This is because local variables are destroyed immediately after the return-statement, and therefore, are safe to just be subsumed into the return value. In this case, you should return by (const-)reference, or `std::move` out the object (if that makes sense, but it doesn't seem like it in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly not a good practice to put raw pointers in std containers. Your type is valid but you have somewhere an unwanted copy that is not authorized. You need to find that part of the code and force a move operation instead.

on EDIT : you probably wants to return by reference like this :

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<tp::QuadTree>, 4> const & get_children() const { return children; }
```

If you want to extract the values and remove them from the initial member, then force a move operation :

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<tp::QuadTree>, 4> extract_children(){ return std::move(children); }
```